# window.scrollTo() stops scrolling after certain height

Tags: html, jquery

I want to scroll the window automatically nearly at the bottom, where there is a `div.row` but when I try

```
let position = $('.pay-card-row').offset().top
window.scrollTo(0, Math.round(position)) # position = 3670px
```

or even

```
window.scrollTo(0, 10000) or
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

it scrolls to a fix vertical height to an element way above the `#pay-card-row`. It scrolls upto `vertical_height = 2623px` and then stops.

I cant add my full page. But If someone has come across this kind of error please help me. Nothing works. But when I tried inspecting the element situated at the very bottom of the page, scrolled manually to the top, and click on the scoll into view option from the context menu in the browser (after pressing F12 and right-clicking on the element), the scroll worked perfectly. It led me to the last element. Somehow Chrome browser's `scrollintoview` function works correctly then my code. I tried every technique available but they gives same output.

Comment: Is the window scrolled down as far as possible? Can it even go any further?

Comment: Check if the zoom is something else than 100%.

Comment: Unable to duplicate problem based on information provided in question.

Comment: @MomasVII no, not as far possible. Stucks at particular height (h1) from the top. If the element height from the top is less than h1 than the scroll animation works properly.

Comment: @Yogi let me try to produce the mvp

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette zoom is 100%

Comment: try to do `window.scrollTo(0, 50)` and then `console.log(window.scrollY)` to see if it works. In my case i had issue where scrollY would stay at 0 because the scroll was on a div

Comment: @Lk77 i tried `window.scrollY` but it stucks at 2623px if the height set in the `window.scrollTo(width, height)` is greater than 2623px. Very weird.